# Error '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, fluttermap

Displaying A-List fetched from a 3rd a Third Party API with the search Function
the error only shows when I ran the App, It Says _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable

Please Welp
*** Edit A new Error Showed after playing with the code this error showed
type *'String' is not a subtype of type Map-dynamic, dynamic-*

```
        Future<Null> getStoreDetails() async {
                var basicAuth = 'Basic ' +
                    base64Encode(utf8.encode('api_token_key'));
                var result;
             
                var response = await http.get(url, headers: {'authorization': basicAuth});
                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                  var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
                  setState(() {
             /Where the error is 
                    for (Map storedetails in responseJson) {
                      _searchResult.add(StoreDetails.fromJson(storedetails));
                    }
                  });
                } else if (response.statusCode != 200) {
                  result = "Error getting response:\nHttp status ${response.statusCode}";
                  print(result);
                }
              }
              @override
              void initState() {
                super.initState();
                getStoreDetails();
              }
```

Data Model Class

```
class StoreDetails {
  final int businessunitid;
  String citydescription;

  StoreDetails({
    this.businessunitid,
    this.citydescription,
  });

   factory StoreDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return new StoreDetails(
      businessunitid: data['businessunitid'],
      citydescription: data['citydescription'],
      
    );
  }
}
```

The Error

```
E/flutter ( 3566): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'
E/flutter ( 3566): #0      SearchStoreState.getStoreDetails.<anonymous closure> (package:rsc_prototype/screens/searchstore_screen.dart:43:34)
E/flutter ( 3566): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1125:30)
E/flutter ( 3566): #2      SearchStoreState.getStoreDetails (package:rsc_prototype/screens/searchstore_screen.dart:42:7)
E/flutter ( 3566): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3566): #3      SearchStoreState.initState (package:rsc_prototype/screens/searchstore_screen.dart:56:5)
E/flutter ( 3566): #4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3751:58)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of `responseJson` is a map. You are trying to do a `for ... in` on it, and that only works with iterables, and maps are not iterables.

You need to figure out the structure of the JSON you receive. It might contain a list that you want to iterate, or you might want to iterate `responseJson.values`. It's impossible to know without knowing the format and what you want to do with it.

If, as you say in a comment below, the JSON is a single object, then your code should probably just be:

```
...
setState(() {
  _searchResult.add(StoreDetails.fromJson(responseJson));
});
...
```

(I don't know enough about Flutter to know whether it's good practice to have an asynchronous initialization of the state, but I expect it to be dangerous - e.g., the widget might get destroyed before the `setState` is called).

Comment: {
"ID": 0,
"BusinessUnitID": 1,
"CompanyCode": "Code",
"Number": 419,
"Name": "Some Name",
"ShortName": "ShortName",
"City": "City City"
},

The JSON format is like this and I only want to retrieve is the city and the businessunitid for the listing and search function

Comment: just learned the different structures of the Json through this article
https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51 
Thanks for answering <3

Comment: and the Json I have is not a list of maps

Answer (score 0):

I you are working with php this is a its working example, remember this `'json_encode($udresponse['userdetails']);` return the appropriate array format you need, and before `array_push($udresponse['userdetails'],$userdetails);` add each item to the array.

```
$udresponse["userdetails"] = array();
$query = mysqli_query($db->connect(),"SELECT * FROM employee WHERE  Employee_Id ='$UserId'") or die(mysqli_error());
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $userdetails= array();
        // user details
        $userdetails["customerid"]=$row["Employee_Id"];
        $userid=$row["Employee_Id"];
        $userdetails["username"]=$UserName;
        $userdetails["fullname"]=$Fullname;
        $userdetails["email"]=$Email;
        $userdetails["phone"]=$Phone;
        $userdetails["role"]=$UserRole;
        $userdetails["restaurantid"]=$RestaurantId;
        array_push($udresponse['userdetails'],$userdetails);
    }  
    $udresponse["success"] = 1;
    $udresponse["message"] = "sign in Successful";
    //echo json_encode($response);
    echo json_encode($udresponse['userdetails']);
} else {   
    $udresponse["success"] = 2;
    $udresponse["message"] = "error retrieving employee details";
    echo json_encode($udresponse);
}
```

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: That was good programming practice thanks AbdelAziz AbdelLatef.

Answer (score 0):

> `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>` is not a subtype of type `Iterable<dynamic>`

I think that you are trying to set the map data to a list.
Map data is coming from the backend and you are trying to set it in a list.

You can simply fix it by returning the array from the backend instead of Map.

Answer (score 0):

I drafted some code which raised this very error, hence how I found this post.

I found the error was caused by treating data from the API with the jsonDecode function too soon.

For example, my draft was `final dynamic responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);` (but the jsonDecode function was used before any sifting was actually called for or wanted).

To resolve the error, I changed my draft to `final dynamic responseData = response.body;` (and left the jsonDecode function for later).

The difference is that the **jsonDecode** function treats the retrieved data, and that must be what led to the error message : )