# Flutter List is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am new in Flutter development. I am getting error

> List is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

I have did this is so far.

Model class

```
class Categories {
final String title;
final Items items;

Categories({this.title, this.items});

 factory Categories.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return new Categories(
    title: json['title'],
    items: Items.fromJson(json['Items']));
  }
}

class Items {
final String tag;
final String childId;
final String category;
final String isNew;

Items({this.tag, this.childId, this.category, this.isNew});

factory Items.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return new Items(
    tag: json['id'],
    childId: json['child_category_id'],
    category: json['category'],
    isNew: json['new']);
 }}
```

Inside maine class

```
List<Categories> categories = [];
var loading = false;

 Future<Null> getNavigationItems() async {
setState(() {
  loading = true;
});

final response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(APIs.url_getCategory2));
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  final data = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));

  setState(() {
    for(Map i in data){
      categories.add(Categories.fromJson(i));
    }


    loading = false;
  });
}
```

}

I am trying to solve issue from 2 days.

This is the format of JSON I am getting from server side [image: JSON structure]

and this is after expanding its first node [image: JSON expanding]

Update images[image: Here is]

[image: Error]

Please help and Thanks.

here is JSON response you can check [Link](https://gist.github.com/Sanwal13/b949470da693b1ba55b5df098eaae63f)

[image: Screen 1]
[image: Screen 2]

Comment: setState(() {
    for(Map i in data){
      categories.add(Categories.fromJson(i));
    }

at this line i am getting error

Comment: _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>')

Comment: How?? I am new in this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209044/discussion-between-sanwal-singh-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink please check image attached.

Comment: It prints JSON.

Comment: Why so? I am searching for the solution.

Comment: can you print json body? It's better than the format Json from server side

Comment: try with List<dynamic> instead of Map and print it all to check the struct in every category

Comment: @hoangquyy  I had added link to check json format. please check

Comment: I see that your json don't have "List" in there, so why you use for.. in.. ? Secondly, it don't have title as you declare in Categories Model

Comment: I want to get key 'SOFAS' as title and reaming as its child. adding 2 more screenshot of app which is running in android

Comment: @hoangquyy check again, screen shot attached.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209057/discussion-between-hoangquyy-and-sanwal-singh).

Comment: I have a similar problem. This error also appears on trying to add to a list an empty list: `myList.addAll(emptyList)`

Answer (score 1):

just check out the modified code I have created a list based on the dynamic JSON object.

```
{
    "icons": {
        "homeIcon": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/home.png",
        "cusomIcon": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/custom.png",
        "looks": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/look-book.png",
        "policyIcon": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/privacy-policy.png",
        "interiorIcon": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/interior.png",
        "emailIcon": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/newsletter.png",
        "aboutusIcon": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/about-us.png"
    },
    "categories": {
        "SOFAS": {
            "icon": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/sofa.png",
            "Items": [{
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "10",
                "category": "SOFA SETS",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "11",
                "category": "Fabric Sofas",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "12",
                "category": "Wooden Sofas",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "298",
                "category": "3 Seater Sofas",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "299",
                "category": "2 Seater Sofas",
                "new": "0",
                "icon": ""
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "666",
                "category": "L Shaped Corner Sofas",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "312",
                "category": "Chesterfield Sofas",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "1079",
                "category": "Recliners",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "120",
                "category": "Futons",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "13",
                "category": "SOFA CUM BED",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "108",
                "category": "Wooden Sofa Cum Beds",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "107",
                "category": "Fabric Sofa Cum Beds",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "13",
                "category": "Sofa Cum Beds",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "",
                "category": "SEATING",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "124",
                "category": "Wingback Chairs",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "36",
                "category": "Lounge Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "40",
                "category": "Chaise Lounge",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "126",
                "category": "Arm Chair",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "42",
                "category": "Stools",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "116",
                "category": "Divans",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "77",
                "category": "Ottomans",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "118",
                "category": "Loveseats",
                "new": "1"
            }]
        },
        "LIVING": {
            "icon": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/living.png",
            "Items": [{
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "16",
                "category": "LIVING STORAGE",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "17",
                "category": "TV Units",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "22",
                "category": "Bookshelves",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "20",
                "category": "Display Unit",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "19",
                "category": "Shoe Racks",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "18",
                "category": "Wall Shelves",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "21",
                "category": "Prayer Units",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "23",
                "category": "Magazine Racks",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "24",
                "category": "TABLES",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "25",
                "category": "Coffee Tables",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "134",
                "category": "Coffee Table Sets",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "27",
                "category": "Nest of Tables",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "135",
                "category": "Side & End Tables",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "26",
                "category": "Console Table",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "116",
                "category": "DIVANS",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "116",
                "category": "Divans",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "38",
                "category": "CHAIRS",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "36",
                "category": "Lounge Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "124",
                "category": "Wing Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "35",
                "category": "Rocking Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "126",
                "category": "Arm Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "130",
                "category": "Metal Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "37",
                "category": "Kids Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "42",
                "category": "Stools",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "43",
                "category": "Benches",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "122",
                "category": "Bean Bags",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "5",
                "category": "OUTDOOR",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "98",
                "category": "Garden Furniture",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "96",
                "category": "Balcony Furniture",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "138",
                "category": "Wooden Swings",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "673",
                "category": "OFFICE FURNITURE",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "681",
                "category": "Office Tables",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "674",
                "category": "Office Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }]
        },
        "BEDROOM": {
            "icon": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/bedroom.png",
            "Items": [{
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "55",
                "category": "BEDS",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "59",
                "category": "Queen Size Beds",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "61",
                "category": "King Size Beds",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "58",
                "category": "Single Beds",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "149",
                "category": "Hydraulic Storage Beds",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "150",
                "category": "Upholstered Beds",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "13",
                "category": "Sofa cum Beds",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "151",
                "category": "Trundle Beds",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "60",
                "category": "Double Beds",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "62",
                "category": "Poster Beds",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "116",
                "category": "Divan Beds",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "65",
                "category": "BEDROOM STORAGE & ACCESSORIES",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "67",
                "category": "Bedside Table",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "101",
                "category": "Chest of Drawers",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "91",
                "category": "Wardrobes",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "68",
                "category": "Dressing Table",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "154",
                "category": "Trunk & Blanket Boxes",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "66",
                "category": "Breakfast Table",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "18",
                "category": "Wall Shelves",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "178",
                "category": "Room Dividers",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "74",
                "category": "Mattress & Bedding",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "548",
                "category": "Mattresses",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "549",
                "category": "Single Bed Mattress",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "551",
                "category": "Queen Size mattress",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "550",
                "category": "King Size Mattress",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "552",
                "category": "Double Bed Mattress",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "155",
                "category": "KIDS BEDROOM",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "64",
                "category": "Bunk Beds",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "63",
                "category": "Kids Beds",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "156",
                "category": "Cribs",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "31",
                "category": "Kids Study Table",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "37",
                "category": "Kids Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }]
        },
        "DINING": {
            "icon": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/dining.png",
            "Items": [{
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "44",
                "category": "DINING ROOM FURNITURE",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "47",
                "category": "6 Seater Dining Sets",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "46",
                "category": "4 Seater Dining Sets",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "49",
                "category": "2 Seater Dining Sets",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "51",
                "category": "Extendable Dining Sets",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "143",
                "category": "Round Dining Sets",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "48",
                "category": "Dining Tables",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "141",
                "category": "8 Seater Dining Sets",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "44",
                "category": "Dining Table Sets",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "383",
                "category": "DINING CHAIRS",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "383",
                "category": "Dining Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "43",
                "category": "Benches",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "11",
                "category": "KITCHEN FURNITURE",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "54",
                "category": "Cabinets & Sideboards",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "177",
                "category": "Kitchen Cabinets",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "190",
                "category": "Kitchen Trolley",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "517",
                "category": "Kitchen Island",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "540",
                "category": "Crockery Unit",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "11",
                "category": "BAR FURNITURE",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "53",
                "category": "Bar Cabinets",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "147",
                "category": "Bar Trolleys",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "148",
                "category": "Wine Racks",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "41",
                "category": "Bar Stools & Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }]
        },
        "STORAGE": {
            "icon": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/stores.png",
            "Items": [{
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "16",
                "category": "LIVING STORAGE",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "17",
                "category": "TV Units",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "22",
                "category": "Bookshelves",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "20",
                "category": "Display Units",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "19",
                "category": "Shoe Racks",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "18",
                "category": "Wall Shelves",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "21",
                "category": "Prayer Units",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "23",
                "category": "Magazine Racks",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "100",
                "category": "BEDROOM STORAGE",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "101",
                "category": "Chest of Drawers",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "91",
                "category": "Wardrobes",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "67",
                "category": "Bedside Tables",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "154",
                "category": "Trunk & Blanket Boxes",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "66",
                "category": "Breakfast Table",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "68",
                "category": "Dressing Table",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "18",
                "category": "Wall Shelves",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "11",
                "category": "DINING STORAGE",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "54",
                "category": "Cabinets & Sideboards",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "177",
                "category": "Kitchen Cabinets",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "190",
                "category": "Kitchen Trolley",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "517",
                "category": "Kitchen Island",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "540",
                "category": "Crockery Unit",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "144",
                "category": "Hutch Cabinets",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "160",
                "category": "BATHROOM STORAGE",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "112",
                "category": "Bathroom Cabinets",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "145",
                "category": "BAR FURNITURE",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "53",
                "category": "Bar Cabinets",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "147",
                "category": "Bar Trolleys",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "148",
                "category": "Wine Racks",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "41",
                "category": "Bar Stools & Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }]
        },
        "STUDY": {
            "icon": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/study.png",
            "Items": [{
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "24",
                "category": "TABLES",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "29",
                "category": "Study Tables",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "30",
                "category": "Laptop Tables",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "31",
                "category": "Kids Study Tables",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "32",
                "category": "Computer Tables",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "11",
                "category": "CHAIRS",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "37",
                "category": "Kids Study Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "159",
                "category": "Study Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "11",
                "category": "STORAGE",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "18",
                "category": "Wall Shelves",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "22",
                "category": "Bookshelves",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "1078",
                "category": "Table Organizer",
                "new": "0"
            }]
        },
        "KIDS FURNITURE": {
            "icon": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/kids.png",
            "Items": [{
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "155",
                "category": "KIDS BEDROOM",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "63",
                "category": "Kids Beds",
                "new": "1"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "64",
                "category": "Bunk Beds",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "156",
                "category": "Cribs",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "157",
                "category": "Kids Storage",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "293",
                "category": "KIDS STUDY ROOM",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "37",
                "category": "Kids Chairs",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "31",
                "category": "Kids Study Tables",
                "new": "0"
            }]
        },
        "DECOR": {
            "icon": "https:\/\/www.woodenstreet.com\/images\/mobileapp\/drawericon\/decor.png",
            "Items": [{
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "74",
                "category": "LAMPS & LIGHTING",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "573",
                "category": "Table Lamps",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "1084",
                "category": "Floor Lamps",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "558",
                "category": "Study Lamps",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "557",
                "category": "Tripod Lamps",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "71",
                "category": "Hanging Lights",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "176",
                "category": "Home Furnishing",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "176",
                "category": "Rugs And Carpets",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "521",
                "category": "Cushions",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "547",
                "category": "Cushion Covers",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "506",
                "category": "Curtains",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "566",
                "category": "Bed Sheets",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "567",
                "category": "Quilts",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "1094",
                "category": "Runners",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "73",
                "category": "Photo Frames",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "73",
                "category": "Photo Frames",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "1085",
                "category": "Single Photo Frames",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "1086",
                "category": "Multi Photo Frames",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "1087",
                "category": "Collage Photo Frames",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "74",
                "category": "Decor Accessories",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "579",
                "category": "Artificial Flowers",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "411",
                "category": "Artificial Plants",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "594",
                "category": "Miniatures",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "1089",
                "category": "Coasters",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "80",
                "category": "Figurines",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "parent",
                "child_category_id": "74",
                "category": "Wall Art",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "1093",
                "category": "Metal Wall Art",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "580",
                "category": "Wall Frames",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "873",
                "category": "Wooden Jharokha",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "74",
                "category": "Mirror Frames",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "1091",
                "category": "Wall Tiles",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "1092",
                "category": "Wall Clocks",
                "new": "0"
            }, {
                "tag": "child",
                "child_category_id": "1090",
                "category": "Wall Murals",
                "new": "0"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

this is the Model class i have created for storing the dynamic data.

```
class Categories {
  String itemName;
  List<Item> items;

  Categories({
    this.itemName,
    this.items,
  });
}

class Item {
  String tag;
  String childCategoryId;
  String category;
  String itemNew;

  Item({
    this.tag,
    this.childCategoryId,
    this.category,
    this.itemNew,
  });

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
        tag: json["tag"],
        childCategoryId: json["child_category_id"],
        category: json["category"],
        itemNew: json["new"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "tag": tag,
        "child_category_id": childCategoryId,
        "category": category,
        "new": itemNew,
      };
}
```

this is the main file where you will get the dynamic data

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sample_project_for_api/NewModel.dart';
import 'package:sample_project_for_api/model.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MyModel yourObject = new MyModel();
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    yourMethod();
  }

  yourMethod() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    String jsonString = await loadFromAssets();

    Map newStringMap = json.decode(jsonString);
    List<Categories> categoryList = new List();
    List<Item> listItem = new List();

    newStringMap['categories'].forEach((key, value) {
      listItem = List<Item>.from(value["Items"].map((x) => Item.fromJson(x)));

      Categories categories = new Categories(itemName: key, items: listItem);
      categoryList.add(categories);
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < categoryList.length; i++) {
      print(
          'This is the item name ############# : ${categoryList[i].itemName}');
      for (int j = 0; j < categoryList[i].items.length; j++) {
        print(
            'This is the item length --------- :${categoryList[i].items[j].category}');
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  Future<String> loadFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('json/parse.json');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.ac_unit), Icon(Icons.access_alarm)],
      )),
      body: Text('sample text'),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: All these "LIVING", "SOFAS", "BEDROOM" objects are dynamic, sometime they comes or sometime not. So I cannot added this in model class as fixed valiable.

Comment: Yes I did, now how to set these value to listview

Comment: In above mentioned image if you have created the ListView just pass the list to item count parameter. If you are having the problem just insert the code of the side navigation so that i can see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `var` Instead of `Map`?

```
for (var i in data) {
          categories.add(Categories.fromJson(i));
        }
```

Comment: Not working. Getting same error - Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>')

Comment: @SanwalSingh okay then try out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51532410/11404883

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't get the keys SOFAR as title with json["title"]. I have rewrite it, let check it out:

```
Map<String, dynamic> categoriesJson = data["categories"];

// get all category name with this because you can't get the key name with "title"
List<String> categoriesName = categoriesJson.keys.map((key) {
  return key.toString();
}).toList();

// depend on the key name, rewrite new Map and put the key name and Items to it
for (String categoryName in categoriesName) {
  Map<String, dynamic> category = {
    "title": categoriesName,
    "Items": categoriesJson[categoriesName]["Items"]
  };

  categories.add(Categories.fromJson(category));
}
```

Comment: Now this error NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("Items"))

Comment: add print(categoryName) in the first line of "for in" and show it to me

Comment: print(categoryName) gives this ---> cat Name : [SOFAS, LIVING, BEDROOM, DINING, STORAGE, STUDY, KIDS FURNITURE, DECOR]

Comment: can you add print("ok") under   Map<String, dynamic> category = {
    "title": categoriesName,
    "Items": categoriesJson[categoriesName]["Items"]
  }; ? I want to check if it wrong or not

Comment: I am not able to write print('ok') inside Map<String, dynamic>. It will not allowed

Comment: No I mean under

Comment: No. It will not reach at bottom, error comes in Map<String, dynamic> category  at   "Items": categoriesJson[categoriesName]["Items"] . It saying "Items" is null