# _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>')

Tags: flutter

**my api response**

```
List<Details> detailsFromJson(String str) =>
    List.from(json.decode(str))
        .map((x) => Details.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>.from(x)))
        .toList();
// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
String detailsToJson(List<Details> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
```

** here the error show _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'). and i want to know what is this type of error,this error show lot of time in my project**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error '\_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532169/error-internallinkedhashmapstring-dynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-iterab)

Comment: helpful.thannk you